# How to make a list of dates for a poly1d equation in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, date

I have:

```
myBuyDate = datetime.date(2020, 11, 19)

x3 = mdates.date2num(myBuyDate)

ax2.axhline(y=f(x3), color='k', ls='dashed')
```

I am not very experienced with python, maybe there is a more straight forward way to do this without using "mdates.date2num()" but that is how I got this to work. So if there is a better way please fill me in. For reference, "f" comes from:

```
fit = np.polyfit(x1, AdClsData, 5)
f = np.poly1d(fit)
```

My question is... I need to enter many different dates on many different subplots using a loop.

Note that:

```
ax2.axhline(y=f(x3), color='k', ls='dashed')
```

is already in a for loop like this:

```
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(myDataColumnCount, 1, figsize=(10, 5*myDataColumnCount))
myax = ax.flat

for i in range(myDataColumnCount):
    ax2 = myax[i].twinx()
```

So I think I can manage the loop part easy enough... What I am struggling with is how to make a "list"? or whatever... of dates... So I am imagining something like this:

```
myDateList = [4/11/2019, 6/7/2019, 11/1/2020, etc...]

fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(myDataColumnCount, 1, figsize=(10, 5*myDataColumnCount))
myax = ax.flat

for i in range(myDataColumnCount):
    ax2 = myax[i].twinx()

    x3[i] = mdates.date2num(myDateList[i])

    ax2.axhline(y=f(x3[i]), color='k', ls='dashed')
```

How do I actually do this?

Comment: In this whole question I can find only a single real question: `What I am struggling with is how to make a "list"?`. Are you only asking how to create a list of some object in python? What would be the logic to create the dates? Why would you show all the irritating plotting code? Please provide copy-able and testify-able code snippets.

Comment: I need to know how to make a list of dates or something like a list of dates. No logic creates the dates (I manually enter dates into this list). The code above shows that I currently have working code for a single date. But the only way I was able to get it to work was: myBuyDate = datetime.date(2020, 11, 19)... this format doesn't seem ideal for making a list? There must be a better way. Furthermore... I was only able to get the single date to work by using: x3 = mdates.date2num(myBuyDate)  before running it through: f = np.poly1d(fit)... There must be a better way...

Comment: Just create some random floats which conform with the [matplotlib.dates.date2num()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) style: `Number of days (fraction part represents hours, minutes, seconds, ms) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, plus one.`. Throw your random number generator in a for-loop and your done: `dates = [ ... for i in range(100)]`

Comment: i don't need random dates... I don't need code to produce dates... I already have specific dates in mind to use. As I said, I plan to "manually" enter the dates. I am sure your solution would work except that it would require me to manually enter the dates in UTC format or whatever its called. Obviously that isn't ideal. I found a solution here: https://samvankooten.net/2018/07/31/dates-in-matplotlib/ but it isn't as clean as I had hoped but it works. Open to suggestions for something simpler. Note: I am not picky about the format I manually enter the dates... as long as its not like UTC

Comment: I will post my solution in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. Again, it isn't as clean as I had hoped, but it works. I came up with this with help from this site: https://samvankooten.net/2018/07/31/dates-in-matplotlib/

```
myBuyDatesSTR = ["2020-12-23", "2021-01-11"]
myBuyDatesDT = []
for date in myBuyDatesSTR:
    y, m, d = (int(x) for x in date.split("-"))
    date = datetime(y, m, d)
    myBuyDatesDT.append(date)

x3 = [mdates.date2num(date) for date in myBuyDatesDT]
```

Also... As I said... My code is already in a loop so I simply changed:

```
ax2.axhline(y=f(x3), color='k', ls='dashed')
```

To:

```
ax2.axhline(y=f(x3[i]), color='k', ls='dashed')
```